# Expl3 - sorting and displaying a seq in Tabularray

Tags: tables, expl3, tabularray, l3seq

I want to print a sequence in a `tblr` environment. The `\sortdata` command accepts the list of integers to be sorted as well as an optional argument to specify how it should be printed out. I want to place `&` as the delimiter of the sequence when printed. This works in a `tabular` environment but not `tblr`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_clear_new:c{l_data_seq}
\seq_clear_new:c{l_sorted_seq}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\sortdata}{O{,}m}{
  \aljumaily_sort:nn{#1}{#2}
   \seq_use:cn{l_sorted_seq}{#1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \aljumaily_sort:nn #1 #2{
  \seq_gset_split:cnn {l_data_seq}{,}{#2}
    \seq_gset_eq:cc{l_sorted_seq}{l_data_seq}
    \seq_gsort:cn {l_sorted_seq} {
        \int_compare:nNnTF {##1} > {##2}{\sort_return_swapped:}{\sort_return_same:}
    }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_gset_split:Nnn {cnn}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}[expand=\expanded]{vlines}
    % \expanded{\sortdata[&]{7, 9, 5, 3}} \\ % Doesn't compile
    % \sortdata[&]{7, 9, 5, 3}            \\ % Doesn't compile
    \expanded{\sortdata[&]{7, 9, 5, 3}}   \\ % Compiles but no output
    \sortdata[,]{7, 9, 5, 3}              \\ % Compiles but cannot place [&]
\end{tblr}

% Works correctly:
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \sortdata[ & ]{7, 9, 5, 3} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your sorting code isn't expandable (even if you use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` for the toplevel, the lower levels aren't)! Instead of using the `\sortdata` inside of the `tblr` environment change its definition to set a temporary macro and expand that inside of `tblr`.

Comment: @Skillmon, Thank you for the explanation. I would appreciate a code snippet as the concept of expansion is something am still trying to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sorts your data into a named sequence, and then uses that named sequence in the `tblr` in an expandable way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\sortdata}{m m}
  {
    \seq_clear_new:c { l_jumaily_data_ #1 _seq }
    \seq_set_from_clist:cn { l_jumaily_data_ #1 _seq } {#2}
    \seq_sort:cn { l_jumaily_data_ #1 _seq }
      {
        \int_compare:nNnTF {##1} > {##2}
          {\sort_return_swapped:}
          {\sort_return_same:}
      }
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\usedata{O{,}m}
  { \seq_use:cn { l_jumaily_data_ #2 _seq } {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\sortdata{test}{7, 9, 5, 3}
\begin{tblr}[expand=\expanded]{vlines}
  \usedata{test} \\
\end{tblr}
\begin{tblr}[expand=\expanded]{vlines}
  \expanded{\usedata[&]{test}} \\
\end{tblr}

% Works correctly:
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \sortdata{test2}{7, 9, 5, 3}\usedata[&]{test2} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want only one function you need to do everything expandable. This is indeed possible, but requires a small detour over the world of token-lists, since currently there is no expandable `clist`-sort (and sequences are completely impossible, there is no expandable sequence creator).

The following implements this detour. You'll still need to trigger the full expansion using `\expanded` in `tblr`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \usesorteddata { O{,} m }
  {
    \exp_not:e
      {
        \__jumaily_output_tl:en
          { \__jumaily_sort:e { \__jumaily_clist_to_tl:n {#2} } }
          {#1}
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__jumaily_sort:n #1
  { \tl_sort:nN {#1} \__jumaily_sort_ascending:nnTF }
\cs_new:Npn \__jumaily_sort_ascending:nnTF #1#2
  { \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} > {#2} \use_ii:nn \use_i:nn }
\cs_new:Npn \__jumaily_clist_to_tl:n #1
  { \clist_map_function:nN {#1} \__jumaily_clist_to_tl_aux:n }
\cs_new:Npn \__jumaily_clist_to_tl_aux:n #1 { { \exp_not:n {#1} } }
\cs_new:Npn \__jumaily_output_tl:nn #1#2
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nF {#1}
      {
        \exp_last_unbraced:Ne \use_none:nn
          { \tl_map_tokens:nn {#1} { \__jumaily_output_tl_aux:nn {#2} } }
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__jumaily_output_tl_aux:nn #1#2
  { \exp_not:n { \exp_not:n {#1} \exp_not:n {#2} } }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__jumaily_output_tl:nn { e }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__jumaily_sort:n { e }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}[expand=\expanded]{vlines}
  \expanded{\usesorteddata[&]{7, 9, 5, 3}} \\
\end{tblr}

% Works correctly:
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \usesorteddata[&]{7, 9, 5, 3} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It seems that `\usedata` cannot accept `&` as the delimiter within the tblr environment. How to fix this?

Comment: @M.AlJumaily by using `\expanded`, see the edit.

Comment: Thanks again. So, there isn't a way for me to use a single command to perform the sorting? I have to sort first and then print individually?

Comment: @M.AlJumaily you could use the expandable sorting code. Currently only `\tl_sort:nN` is available expandably, you could use `\clist_map_function:nN` to first normalise the `clist` into a `tl`-list, then sort that thing, then map your output using `\tl_map_function:nN`. It is possible, but harder to code correctly.

Comment: @Skillmon The `l_jumaily_data_` should be declared outside the macros as a global sequence.

Comment: @projetmbc no, since the sequence's name depends on the provided first argument this isn't possible. This is according to the L3-styleguide.

Comment: @Skillmon Oups. I have missed the c argument... ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the update and assistance :).